# I already have the entry but still no pg_hba.conf entry for host "X.X.X.X", SSL off

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to connect to a database **whose entry is already in pg_hba.conf file** but still showing the error

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "X.X.X.X", user "abcuser", database "abc", SSL off.

I have searched a lot but still got no answer. Anyone pls help.

[image]

Comment: What is `"X.X.X.X"` ? Your ph_hba.conf file only has entries for 127.0.0.1

Comment: How can you expect an answer if we cannot see the file and know the exact parameters used to connect? Are you afraid anyone might steal your data because they know your IP address and the name of your database?

Comment: The problem is solved. This was because the IP address of the database server was previously hard coded to some wrong address in one specific part of the program. I changed it and made it to be fetched from config.properties file and it works. Thank you all..that was a silly mistake ;)